# How to set root password on Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, passwords, amazon-ec2, root

At first, I SSHed into an instance as 'ubuntu' user, typed 'sudo -s', and it didn't ask me for the root password. Then I entered 'passwd' as 'root' user and typed twice the new password, and confirmed them.

But the next time I SSH into this instance as 'ubuntu' user, type 'sudo -s', and it still doesn't ask me for any password!

Am I missing something?

The instance runs Ubuntu 8.04(Hardy).

Comment: I see...I checked the /etc/sudoers as https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo described, and found that the 'ubuntu' user is the default user and made no password to use root privilege.

Comment: I heard you should only use a passwordless root for SSH to EC2 otherwise you'll be locked outside and have to detach/attach the EBS volume and fixed it with a temporary instance. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`/etc/sudoers`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers). There is defined whether you need a password (and if root's or your own one) for the diverse invocations of `sudo`.

Comment: I think it worth noting that messing up with this file will totally blew up the instance... As the solutions to fix a broken /etc/sudoers requires a password.